# how to disble menu item for ContextMenu in android

Tags: android, menu

I would like to apply context Menu to one `textview`. And I would like to set cut, copy, paste to be disable when string clipboard is empty and when string clipboard not empty I would like to make cut, copy, paste to be enable.

First I assign variable clipboard to empty

```
String clipboard = "";
```

Then

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context, menu);

    if(clipboard ==""){
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_cut).setEnabled(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_copy).setEnabled(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_paste).setEnabled(false);
    }else{
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_cut).setEnabled(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_copy).setEnabled(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_paste).setEnabled(true);
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

But it not work... even clipboard is empty but items menu still enable.

Comment: you're confusing the string matching in java. its clipboard.equals("") and not == for comparison

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context, menu);

if("".equals(clipboard)) {  // if clipboard is null this will not throw a NPE
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_cut).setEnabled(false);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_copy).setEnabled(false);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_paste).setEnabled(false);
} else {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_cut).setEnabled(true);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_copy).setEnabled(true);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_paste).setEnabled(true);}
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant compare String value with "==" must use the equal like below :

```
if(clipboard.equals("")){
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_cut).setEnabled(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_copy).setEnabled(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_paste).setEnabled(false);}
               }

         else {
           menu.findItem(R.id.action_cut).setEnabled(true);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_copy).setEnabled(true);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_paste).setEnabled(true);
         }
         super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        }
```

Comment: @user3785958 your welcome. if problem solved choose the best answer. Good Luck